# Gridview data display on demand of user

Tags: asp.net

I have connected GridView with a datasource. It works fine but it is displayed just at form load. I want to show it when user clicks the button. How to make it so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the Visible attribute of the GridView to false. In the Click handler of the button, set the Visible attribute of the GridView to true. Rebind and use an update panel if necessary.

If you post some source code, we can give you a working example.